# have different values for "active" in my jQuery accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Im using jQuery accordion, and it is working fine.

Im using active:0, to  have my first tab open, when I acess a page.

But Im using accordion in diferent php files, like "schedule.php" and "organization.php".

And In "schedule.php" I want that my active is like I have in my script below (active:0).

But in my "organization.php", I want that my active is 1, (active:1).

Do you know how I can do this, without being repeating my script several times for each page?

```
$(function (){

    $('.accordion').accordion({
        active: 0,   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your javascript code in a separate file and modify your php scripts to add a class to activate / deactivate and include your javascript file to both php files using:

```
<script src="/path/to/js/file.js"></script>
```

e.g javascript file

```
$(function (){

    $('.accordion.inactive').accordion({
        active: 0,   
    });
    $('.accordion.active').accordion({
        active: 1,   
    });
});
```

Then in `schedule.php` add a class `inactive` to your accordion div
and in `organization.php` add a class `active` to your accordion div

Comment: Thank you Medhat Gayed, it was exaclty that what Im trying to get! But, for example I have more options in my script like collapsible: true, this option I need to repeat in both right? (in inactive and active)

Comment: Im getting a little bug with your solution. I have my '.accordion.inactive' with active:false, and When I acess my page with this inactive accordion, I see my accordion to shrink and then gets my active:false, with none tab open. But Im seeing this shrink effect, do you know why this is happening?

Comment: The shrink effect could be something to do with where / at what point  you load the javascript file i.e. at the top or bottom of your php script, and it could lag a bit before the js is executed. you could initially hide the accordion div and then show it when your javascript has run to avoid the issue.

Comment: Yes to your first question. you need to repeat the options for each mode.

Comment: Thanks Medhat Gayed. And for the bug Im getting do you know how I can solve this?